# How to convert from listArray to String[ ]

Tags: arrays, string

My input can be as follows:

```
"a b c", "123", "ade341"
```

How do I create an `String[]` from this list of input?

```
   list<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
   String[] array1 = new String(list.size());
   list.toArray(array1);
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: How does it not work?  Runtime error?  Compile-time error?  What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your initialization of the string array should be `String[] arr = new String[list.size()];`.
Otherwise you call the constructor of the String-Class.

Answer (score 1):

Plese try this

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
 String[] array1 = new String[arr.size()];
 arr.toArray(array1);
```

this should work